# New projects not being built in a solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio

We have a solution under which there are many class library projects. The previous developer created some class library projects in the solution. Later I started adding some new projects. The problem is, when I build the solution locally everything works as expected. But when I deploy the solution to development servers, the build does not include any new projects included in the solution. All the previously added projects seem to get deployed appropriately.
I did check the configuration manager to make sure all the projects are being included in both Debug and Release mode, but I still have the issue. 
Can someone point where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: It would help to know: What version of VS? What kind of solution/project (desktop app, web app,...)? How exactly you are deploying (wizard, menu item)? Are there any post Build Events in the project properties? How did you link the new projects' references to the solution?

Comment: I would peek into the source text of the solution/project files and see if there are any differences between the working project and non-working projects.   Use Notepad.

Comment: @SteveWellens: I found a work around to manually include the project dependencies in the .csproj file. I am not sure if this is the ideal way to do but for now it is working.

Comment: @Uma Glad you got it working.  Maybe I should have suggested WinMerge instead of Notepad.   It's free and great for comparing text files.